# How to color a 3D object with slide/tap (dynamically) in Swift 2.1

Tags: swift, 3d, sprite-kit, textures, scenekit

I have to build a Swift app that can color a 3D object with various gestures. I have a Collada file that I imported as a SceneKit object. I can't find a way to color it with tap. I tried to convert Obj-C from the WWDC example but it's not working for me.

I tried to apply a SpriteKit as texture on the 3D object but that's the result:

As the user taps the screen, the app should take the coordinates of the texture of the 3D object and then add in that point a SpriteKit node.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: object after run]

I don't know why the texture explode in that way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SpriteKit scene coordinate system doesn't map to texture coordinates in the same way an image does. Pixel coordinates in an image have the y-axis increasing downward; in a SpriteKit scene, the y-axis goes up.

This is a lot more apparent if you just map that SpriteKit scene onto an `SCNPlane` that's the only thing in a SceneKit scene — you'll see that the image is flipped.

Left: Image as loaded from bundle, Right: Image filling an `SKScene` mapped to a plane (with annotations)

[image: base image]
[image: image in SKScene on SCNMaterial]

To fix this, you'll need a two-step coordinate transformation:

1. Translate the origin y-coordinate up by the height of the `SKScene`
2. Scale y-coordinates by -1 so that increasing coordinates go down, not up

[image: coordinate transformation]

You can do this either within the `SKScene`, or in the `SCNMaterialProperty` that texture-maps the SpriteKit content onto a SceneKit object. I favor the `SCNMaterialProperty` approach — just set the appropriate matrix for its [`contentsTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterialProperty_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNMaterialProperty/contentsTransform) property:

```
let translate = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 1, 0)
let yFlippedTranslate = SCNMatrix4Scale(translate, 1, -1, 1)
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = yFlippedTranslate
```

Note that if you're also trying to map touch/click events into the SpriteKit scene using the material's texture coordinates (via `SCNHitTestResult`), you'll need to perform a similar transformation there:

```
let texcoord = result.textureCoordinatesWithMappingChannel(0)
sprite.position.x = texcoord.x * skScene.size.width
sprite.position.y = (1 - texcoord.y) * skScene.size.height
```